# How to do CRC check on executable loaded in memory?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, crc32

I want to run a thread that checks the memory image of the current executable, for protection reasons. Any ideas how to do CRC on the current memory executable (WinAPI or .NET way)? My app is written in .NET.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? As a hacker, if I can change your code (wich will reside in a ReadOnly page, so I will need proper rights to modify it), I can also disable this check. Plus, DEP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) is probably already protecting your code.

Comment: I'm trying to make my code hard to modify from debuggers.

Comment: Sorry @blez, but @Simon Mourier is right. How is your crc-checking code any more secure than the rest?

Comment: What about the fixups? You ain't ever gonna deal with those!

Comment: If I run several threads that check the self crc32 in 5+n minute interval for example, my app will quit on the first memory modification that the cracker makes.

Comment: @David Heffernan: well I hope there is a way to get the whole image and it doesn't change often

Comment: If you're prepared to write a bit of C you can check to see whether or not you're being debugged.

Comment: @Jimmy: with the IsDebuggerPresent api?

Comment: @blez How do you know that your code isn't modifying itself. Who says that your jitter won't do that? There are techniques to fight back against attacks but I don't think this is one.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Any other advices for checking the code in memory?

Comment: @blez No, this is a seriously hard problem. I'd be looking for tools rather than trying to (re)invent this particular wheel.

Comment: yes, using IsDebuggerPresent - come to think of it, you can probably P/Invoke it. A lot of the personal firewalls also hook functions like OpenProcess etc to catch people trying to debug your process. You can check to see whether you're inside a VM... You can make it difficult, but you can never make it impossible.

Comment: @blez: `IsDebuggerPresent` will not do much. Neither will doing a CRC periodically. What you are doing here is punishing the folks who actually purchased your app by slowing down their machines. The counter to all your hard work is simple: attach a debugger, modify values, and detach. Your code will never know it was debugged, and your periodic checks have now been disabled by the patch.

Comment: @tenfour: That's why I wrote that I'll do several threads that change the thing. To make the modification harder.

Comment: @blez: threads won't help you. The debugger halts your whole process. Even if you make different processes that do mutual checks, anyone that can use a debugger will be able to attach a debugger to both of them within milliseconds. Or use a kernel debugger. The pirated version of your app will perform much better. By trying to subvert this, you are only punishing legitimate owners.

Comment: @tenfour: you're not helping me. I'm aware that this slows down the program and can be cracked. But the idea is to be hard to crack.

Comment: What if next patch of CLR will add re-JIT-ing of frequently called methods... or something similar?

Comment: @blez: I am trying to save you time, and save your users. Using threads / periodic CRC checks will *not make it any harder* to crack your app. Detaching the debugger after patching is all it takes. It is wasted effort. Cracks are distributed in binary form anyway; how are your runtime checks supposed to protect against patching the EXE itself?

Comment: @tenfour: It will make the whole cracking process longer. Also my app checks it's file CRC, I just want it in memory too to make sure that it's hardly changeable

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: That would be bad. I'll need to test it with x86/x64 win and different systems.

Comment: @blez: threads do not make the cracking process any longer. And detaching a debugger is so trivial that it might as well be nothing. I am not trying to bash you, I want you to find a solution that is the best bang for the buck, and doesn't annoy users. Make them WANT to buy your app. Doing periodic runtime checks on a CRC is definitely not a good return for your effort, especially in the strategies you've proposed, sorry...

Comment: @tenfour: The users don't even know what CRC is, and they won't know that's going on background. Whatever, tell me better solution if this is that bad.

Comment: @blez: Users don't know what a CRC is, but they know what slow performance is. This whole situation is rather frustrating, I agree. It's just the nature of software, and a clean solution doesn't exist. Current workarounds are extremely sophisticated though which you really don't want to commit yourself to implementing. I suggest a 3rd party solution.

Comment: :) If your users don't know what CRC is how they will patch assembly in memory and update internal CLR tables to force JIT to happen for newly modified methods? You need to build you treat model that makes sence first - than decide on what method to use to protect your code (simple obfuscation, run critical code on your own server, convert all to hand-modified native code...)

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: as users I'm talking about normal users, not crackers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signing your assemblies will give you as good verification as you can get with relation to verify CRC of .Net assembly (see Rodrigo's answer).

If you are worried that someone will patch assembly at runtime you probably worried too much. It requires better understanding of runtime to in memory patch IL for a method that is already JIT'ed compared to simply disassembling your .Net code and fixing it up (including removal of your CRC checks).

If you doing it more for fun than you shoud be able to find base address where assembly is loaded and compute CRC of some sort... or see if pages are marked as modified...

Answer (score 2):

I think that's going to be quite difficult in .NET. When an executable is loaded, it can potentially be split up and loaded into several different regions in memory. You'll need to acquaint yourself with the Window's Executable format:
http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/platform/firmware/PECOFF.mspx

as well as the Windows executable loading process.

You'll might also want to concern yourself with depenency dlls as well. You'll be making so many native calls, that you might want to consider doing this in C.

Not much of an answer, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Any runtime check you do will have the following drawbacks:

1. False positives. Because this is .NET, you cannot assume the runtime doesn't modify your in-memory code. You may detect a hack where there is none.
2. Any run-time check you make will be no more secure than the code you are trying to protect. This includes **any** runtime mechanism you create in your app such as periodic CRC checks, sentinel processes, or even checking with a server where the request can be faked.
3. You will decrease performance in your legitimate application, where the pirated version will run better without all these checks
4. You will do nothing to solve patching your EXE.

I understand that you are just trying to make it as hard as possible, even though it's not 100% uncrackable. But the solutions you propose (and likely any solution you can implement yourself) will do extremely little to thwart any average cracker.

Because this is such a demanded feature though, I would look for 3rd party solutions where they have put forth the effort for a sophisticated solution which can be updated as cracking techniques evolve. I cannot recommend any personally though.

Comment: Everything can be patched, that's true. My code was obfuscated, but still patched. Now I'm trying my best to make it hard for crack. But I find disturbing only 1) - that .net modifies its memory executable.

Comment: I guess I'll just check the file only.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a way to do this in .NET. 
If you are interested in protecting you executables, you can generate a new key with `sn` and add it to AssemblyInfo.cs, so that if the application is modified at least it will not run.

Answer (score 0):

[Jon Skeet's Miscellaneous Utility Library](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) contains a method to compute the [Adler32 checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adler-32) on a stream. Its usage would be:

```
MiscUtil.Checksum.Adler32.ComputeChecksum(stream);
```

As for creating a memorystream out of the assembly that is currently running... I don't know if that is even possible (or advisable).

Comment: "...creating a memorystream out of the assembly that is currently running..."... eek! :)